# Is it possible to have a custom option for a product that, when selected, disables all the other options?

Tags: custom-options, magento-1.6, magento-1

Is it possible to have a custom option available for a product that, when selected, disables all the other custom options for that product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not support this by default but there are extensions that do this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dependent-custom-options.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dependent-custom-options-gallery.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dependent-custom-options-configurable-3523.html
http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html

These are just the first 4 links I found while searching on Google

Comment: Thanks for the links - I searched for a while but found nothing due to not searching for the correct wording...